# Groovy - Merge/Group By List of Maps

Tags: groovy, hashmap, mergemap

I have a list of maps that follows the structure `List<Map<String,List<String>>>`

```
List<Map<String,List<String>>> lstData = []
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Oct"],"Account":["A1000","A1001"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Oct"],"Account":["A1001","A1002"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Nov"],"Account":["A1000","A1001","A1002"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Dec"],"Account":["A1000","A1002"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY20"],"Period":["Jan"],"Account":["A1000","A1003"]]
```

I have been trying to build something that would output a list in a similar structure as the input, but merged:

```
List<Map<String,List<String>>> lstTarget = []
lstTarget << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Oct","Nov"],"Account":["A1000","A1001","A1002"]]
lstTarget << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Dec"],"Account":["A1000","A1002"]]
lstTarget << ["Year":["FY20"],"Period":["Jan"],"Account":["A1000","A1003"]]
```

Notice how Oct / Nov of FY19 both ultimately had the same accounts, so they were grouped together (this isn't super important if it can't be done)

I have tried several iterations here but every time I go down a rabbit hole I get further away from a "groovy" solution. Below is what I have :

```
List lstDims = lstData[0].keySet() as List
List<Map<String,List<String>>> lstOut = []
def result = lstData.groupBy{o -> lstDims.dropRight(1).collect{o."$it"}}.values()
result.each { item ->
    lstOut << item*.keySet().flatten().unique().collectEntries{
        [(it): item*.get(it).findAll().flatten().unique()]
    }
}
println lstOut

// Gets a List Like Below
/*
[
  [Year:[FY19], Period:[Oct], Account:[A1000, A1001, A1002]], 
  [Year:[FY19], Period:[Nov], Account:[A1000, A1001, A1002]], 
  [Year:[FY19], Period:[Dec], Account:[A1000, A1002]], 
  [Year:[FY20], Period:[Jan], Account:[A1000, A1003]]
]
*/

// Repeat to group back by account, ultimately providing the Target List: 

result = lstOut.groupBy{o -> lstDims.takeRight(1).collect{o."$it"}}.values()
lstOut = []
result.each { item ->
    lstOut << item*.keySet().flatten().unique().collectEntries{
        [(it): item*.get(it).findAll().flatten().unique()]
    }
}
println lstOut
assert lstOut == lstTarget
```

A two issues I am having with this

1. it doesn't feel very "groovy" but I am still relatively new to groovy so what do I know
2. I have to "hard code" the keys within in the groupBy closure : `.groupBy{"${it.Year}${it.Period}"}` -- I can't figure out a way to pass it 1 or more keys to group by on.

In regards to #2 above I will have a list of keys to group by when this code is executed, but when I can't figure out how to a I use this in the `.groupBy{sGroupBy}` - I was trying something like below

**EDIT --**
Figured out #2, not sure if it is the best way, but it works

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a knotty one that...

You *could* do this:

```
List<Map<String,List<String>>> lstData = []
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Oct"],"Account":["A1000","A1001"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Oct"],"Account":["A1001","A1002"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Nov"],"Account":["A1000","A1001","A1002"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY19"],"Period":["Dec"],"Account":["A1000","A1002"]]
lstData << ["Year":["FY20"],"Period":["Jan"],"Account":["A1000","A1003"]]

lstData.groupBy { it.Year + it.Period }.collect { k, v ->
   v.tail().inject(v.head()) { r, c -> r.Account = (r.Account + c.Account).unique(); r }
}.groupBy { it.Account }.collect { k, v ->
   v.tail().inject(v.head()) { r, c -> 
       r.Year = (r.Year + c.Year).unique()
       r.Period = (r.Period + c.Period).unique()
       r
   }
}
```

Not sure if it's better than yours though